# Mysql convert hex string into decimal string

Tags: mysql, string, hex, decimal

I would like to convert an hexstring into a decimal string:

eg:
date in sql colum = 150910 where 15 is yy and 09 is mm and 10 is dd. (150910 is a string)
So the final result should look like 210916

Anybody an idea?

Comment: ??? `150910` is not hex, what makes you thinks its hex, its just a date stored in a difficult to manage way

Comment: If you convert this 15 hex = 21 decimal // 09 = 09 and 10 = 16. So it's today's date

Comment: Divide to separate parts, convert, concatenate back.

Comment: you have the SQL syntax to do this?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28d7f3146d285811a1aa6eadb7719f89

Comment: Possibly your app language can do the task more easily.